# Draw Cursor in Custom View using StaticLayout (multiline)

Tags: view, cursor, paint, staticlayout

If I have:

```
new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, alignment, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
```

How to draw Cursor in text?